# What is HTML's <a></a> tag default display type?

Tags: html, css

I haven't been able to find anything that says what the default display is equivalent to in CSS's display properties. I ask, because whenever I attempt to add padding or margin to an `<a>` tag, it doesn't add it, I have to add the display property of `inline-block` for it to.

I don't know if this is browser specific or not, but would the default display of it be `inline` versus say `inline-block` (I obviously know it's not `inline-block`.

Comment: You can always define the default style to a GLOBALLY

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/QBvSW/)

Comment: @PeeHaa interesting, so it does. I suppose it must be something in one of my parent elements that messes it up along the way or something weird like that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is always `display: inline` by default. Horizontal margins, and padding on all sides should work without having to change its `display` property.

This remains true even in HTML5. If you are applying styles to an `<a>` element that contains flow elements or any other elements that are represented in CSS as `display: block`, you should set the `<a>` itself to a proper block container type such as `block` or `inline-block` for its layout to work as intended.

Comment: Technically, the *defaults* are browser-dependent. The *initial* value of `display` is `inline`. There is nothing in HTML specifications or drafts that a browser style sheet should set `display` to some other value for `a` elements. But it could. (If a browser ever does that, it will hardly set it to `inline-block`. Rather something like `-coolbrowser-inline-with-extra`.)

Comment: @Jukka: Yep. I should clarify my answer - I was thinking in terms of both HTML and CSS; in this case, the default CSS (which as you say is in fact browser dependent) is similar to, or exactly, `display: inline` based that initial value, and the HTML spec which doesn't say anything about what it *should* be...

Comment: If the default display type is `inline`, when why does setting margin work? Margin does not work for other elements that are inline by default, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's INLINE by default.
Inline-block is not supported in IE7.

margin is not supported in Inline element. and only left & right padding is supported in INLINE element.

Comment: Why wouldn't margin be supported?

Comment: because it's an inline element. You will have to make it either block or inline-block to apply margin

Comment: I meant top bottom margin wont be supported, same as padding