# css background image css does not work with ul attribute

Tags: html, css

im having problems with the background image attribute inside an ul

this is the html:

```
<ul class="nav" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<li style="display: table-cell;"><a class="facebook1" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
    <li style="display: table-cell;"><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/MobilityGo1" target="_block"></a></li>
    <li style="display: table-cell;"><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/bcmlpn" target="_block"></a></li>
    <li style="display: table-cell;"><a class="pinterest" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
    <li style="display: table-cell;"><a class="instagram" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
</ul>
```

the css:

```
/*social icons*/

a.facebook1 {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
background: url("/files/assets/facebook1.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
}
a.twitter {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
background: url("/files/assets/twitter.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
}
a.youtube {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
background: url("/files/assets/youtube.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
}
a.pinterest {
width: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
height: 30px;
background: url("/files/assets/pinterest.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
}
a.instagram {
width: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;
height: 30px;
background: url("/files/assets/instagram.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 30px 30px;
}
/*social icons*/
```

the class a.social network shows the icon but is not showing the first icon

for example the a.facebook1 dont shows when we display in the web page.

if i add another social icon class before a.facebook1 wont show and the other icons including facebook1 will show

http://prntscr.com/6chstf

update:

i solved moving those lines to the top of the css file

Comment: Do you have anything above `a.facebook1 {` that could be breaking your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding following to the CSS

```
.nav li > a { display: block;}
```

Comment: Can you show the CSS class that you have before `/*social icons*/`

Comment: @media (max-width: 1280px) {
.container .text-muted {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div.facebook-box-out {
padding: 8px;
border: 1px solid #284470;
position: relative;
background: url("http://o1.t26.net/img/facebook-box.gif") no-repeat scroll 60px 3px #005AA2;
}

.walmart {
padding-left: 5px;
background: url("/files/assets/walmart.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 117px 30px;
}
.comer {
padding-left: 5px;
background: url("/files/assets/comercialmexicana.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 117px 30px;
}

}

Comment: i just solved the problem moving the lines to the top of the file

Comment: Check if you have any CSS class attribute not ending with `;` or find if there is any missing `}` in the CSS file

Comment: the problem was i found a " next to border-radius: 0;

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul class="nav" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <li><a class="facebook1" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
        <li><a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/MobilityGo1" target="_block"></a></li>
        <li><a class="youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/bcmlpn" target="_block"></a></li>
        <li><a class="pinterest" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
        <li><a class="instagram" href="https://www.facebook.com/demo" target="_block"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
/*social icons*/

    .nav a{
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        background-size: 30px 30px;
        display: block;  
    }

    .nav li{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    a.facebook1 {
        background: url("/files/assets/facebook1.png") no-repeat;
    }
    a.twitter {   
        background: url("/files/assets/twitter.png") no-repeat;
    }
    a.youtube {
        background: url("/files/assets/youtube.png") no-repeat;
    }
    a.pinterest {
        background: url("/files/assets/pinterest.png") no-repeat;
    }
    a.instagram {
        background: url("/files/assets/instagram.png") no-repeat;
    }
    /*social icons*/
```

Remove style="display: table-cell;" from the li and set the display to inline-block, on the a tag change it to display block, an a tag does not use the height css property until the display is set to block or inline block.

See the post below for a more in depth overview
[What is HTML's <a></a> tag default display type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548225/what-is-htmls-a-a-tag-default-display-type)