# center nav elements bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know things like this have been asked here before, but the previous answers haven't solved my problem. I need to center the nav bar elements on my page. I've tried text-align: center on the div, nav and a tags, but no luck. I need it to be responsive as well so the nav bar stays centered as the page is resized.

```
       <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
              <a class="blog-nav-item" href="/">item</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

update: it is slight more centered when I put the div holding the navbar inside my container-fluid and change it to a regular container, but it looks like the text is still not centered in the div. I would also like to keep a container-fluid if I can.

Comment: it appears to work in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0xw3bwt/)

Comment: @php_nub_qq strange. do you know of a reason why it does not respond the same on my browser? i'm using chrome and the javascript console shows that all jquery / js / bootstrap resources are being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers renders the HTML elements by their own set of rules.
This is why you want to make sure to tell the browser not to go all anarchistic on you.

The main problems you might encounter are the rules of the text-align function. It does not work on inline-elements, but on inline-block elements.

See this Fiddle and try it out in your browsers.
http://jsfiddle.net/39ppmgdf/

Notice the `display:inline-block;`

The reason you are experiencing some difficulties here is because of the anchor .

Read the answer of this post to understand more:

[What is HTML's <a></a> tag default display type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548225/what-is-htmls-a-a-tag-default-display-type)