# Padding for <a> tag inside navigation <ul><li> </ul></li>

Tags: css

I'm writing CSS for a website. At one point, I have mentioned `padding` for anchor tag which is inside nav `ul li`. I have given some padding to a tag. It is working fine for Chrome but not for Firefox. For Firefox, it needs some different `padding`. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Show us your `HTML` markup and `CSS`

Comment: Please `http://jsfiddle.net/` create a fiddle sample to show your scenario

Comment: This helps you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548225/what-is-htmls-a-a-tag-default-display-type

Comment: My guess is that both the ul and the li have margins and/or paddings of their own, and if you set all margins and paddings explicitly, the differences will go away.