# HTML Navigation bar styling

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'd like to color my menu points:
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mlEB.png)

But only the text's background is colored. How can I change my code to fill the whole menu to match the color in the picture above?

```css
    nav{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 8vh;
        background-color: #F39C12 ;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .nav_links{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 35%;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .nav_links li{
        background-color: #DAF7A6;
    }
    .nav_links a{
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: whitesmoke;
    }
```

```html
    <!-- navigation bar -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Kezdőlap</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Képek</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Videók</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Játék</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Have a nice day! Thank you!

Comment: Please turn your example code into a snippet (the `[<>]` button) so we can help directly. Your first step might be to make `.nav_links a` be `display: inline-block;`. See answer for [default a styling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13548234/10441671)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add padding to your `li` tag.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #F39C12;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav_links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 35%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav_links li {
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
  /* EDITED HERE */
  padding: 20px;
}

.nav_links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!-- navigation bar -->
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_links">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Kezdőlap</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Képek</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Videók</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Játék</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add border styling in order to achieve the attached image.

```
border: 1px solid ;
```

You can give any color you want in place of solid to design a colorful border

Comment: Sorry i was not clear. I want to color the menu point's background not just the borders. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/rh6jvik