# increase size of navbar-brand

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm building a landing page but my logo is looking very small and i~m using bootstrap 5

style.css

```
...
.navbar-brand {
  width: 3.5rem;
  padding: 0 0;
  margin: 0.3rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

body .navbar-brand .logo-dark {
  display: none;
}

body.dark-layout .navbar-brand .logo-light {
  display: none;
}

body.dark-layout .navbar-brand .logo-dark {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-expand-sm .navbar-brand {
    width: 4.5rem;
  }

  .navbar-expand-sm.headroom--not-top:not(.headroom--pinned):not(.headroom--bottom) {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .navbar-expand-sm .nav-item {
    height: 4.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-expand-sm .nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-brand {
    width: 4.5rem;
  }

  .navbar-expand-md.headroom--not-top:not(.headroom--pinned):not(.headroom--bottom) {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .navbar-expand-md .nav-item {
    height: 4.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-expand-md .nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-brand {
    width: 4.5rem;
  }

  .navbar-expand-lg.headroom--not-top:not(.headroom--pinned):not(.headroom--bottom) {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .navbar-expand-lg .nav-item {
    height: 4.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-expand-lg .nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-expand-xl .navbar-brand {
    width: 4.5rem;
  }

  .navbar-expand-xl.headroom--not-top:not(.headroom--pinned):not(.headroom--bottom) {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .navbar-expand-xl .nav-item {
    height: 4.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-expand-xl .nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .navbar-expand-xxl .navbar-brand {
    width: 4.5rem;
  }

  .navbar-expand-xxl.headroom--not-top:not(.headroom--pinned):not(.headroom--bottom) {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .navbar-expand-xxl .nav-item {
    height: 4.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar-expand-xxl .nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
  }
}

.navbar-expand .navbar-brand {
  width: 4.5rem;
}
...
```

This is my html file

```
[![...
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-sticky navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid px-xl-0 mx-xl-5">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo-no-background.svg') }}" alt="" class="">

      </a>
...][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `navbar-brand` size isn't changing because its display is `inline` as [`<a>` tag has `display:inline` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13548234/13927534).

add `display:block` to the `navbar-brand` and your `width` will take effect:

```
.navbar-brand {
    width: 3.5rem;
    padding: 0 0;
    margin: 0.3rem 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. I changed the css file and the logo is still small

Comment: the code you provided does not reproduce that behavior, idk what other css or html you have but when I added `display:block` I was able to modify the width and height. We need more context to know what's happening with you exactly