# Why the (a) tag appeared next to the image not below it?

Tags: html

Why the anchor(a) tag appeared next to the image and not below it? isn't the page suppose to be read from up to bottom?

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<h2>Falafel</h2>
<p>Chickpea, herbs and spices.</p>
<img src="flafel.jpeg" width="240" height="135" alt="Flafel">
<h2>Pasta Salad</h2>
<p>Lettuce, vegetables and mozzarella.</p>
<img src="salad.jpg" width="240" height="135" alt="Salad">
<a href="location.html">Our Location</a>
```

I was trying to practice some html basics but this problem happened and can't find an explanation for it.

Comment: `<img>` has a `display` value of `inline` by default, just like `<a>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Welcome! Both `img` and `a` tags are **inline** elements. [MDN information on the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#examples_of_different_display_types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is HTML's <a></a> tag default display type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548225/what-is-htmls-a-a-tag-default-display-type)

Comment: Why would you expect them to not be on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is occuring because image (`img`) and anchor (`a`) tags are both [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Inline-level_content).

To solve this issue, you should wrap the `img` tag into a block element (such as a `div`) as follows:

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<h2>Falafel</h2>
<p>Chickpea, herbs and spices.</p>

<div>
  <img src="flafel.jpeg" width="240" height="135" alt="Flafel">
</div>

<h2>Pasta Salad</h2>
<p>Lettuce, vegetables and mozzarella.</p>

<div>
  <img src="salad.jpg" width="240" height="135" alt="Salad">
</div>

<a href="location.html">Our Location</a>
```